# How to fetch data from two tables info using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get data from two tables. I have patient first name and last name in one table and appointment time in other table. I am using following way but it gives an error:

```
SELECT    
    PatientMaster.PatientFirstName,
    PatientMaster.PatientLastName,
    ProviderAppointmentListings.AppointmentTime 
FROM PatientMaster 
    JOIN ProviderAppointmentListings 
    ON PatientMaster.PatientID = ProviderAppointmentListings.PatientID


$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

it prints here query empty

Comment: Please quote the exact error message. Better yet, use the search to search for other questions with this exact error message. I'm sure you'll find plenty.

Comment: relation between the table? is it one-to-one or one-to-many?

Comment: @shiplu how to check relation b/c i have clients data base on server how may check that there is relation or not

Comment: What is the point of that json_encode() function ? your question is about the SQL .. ins't it ?

Comment: my question is in sql but it has also included function to get data and convert

Comment: Json encode has nothing to do here. I Remove this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDITED]**

Try:

```
$query="SELECT PatientMaster.FirstName,PatientMaster.LastName,ProviderAppointmentListings.AppointmentTime 
FROM PatientMaster JOIN ProviderAppointMentListings ON PatientMaster.PatientID = ProviderAppointmentListings.PatientId";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

If a MySQL error appears, then there must be something wrong with your query.

Comment: it is givning same error mysql fetch []

Comment: try it using @ramil amir's code

Comment: yes i am using @ramil code but again same error

Comment: try adding 

$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());//<=== add this line

and see what happens it might be that your query is wrong...

Comment: Query was empty it prints this result

Comment: @prukhukoo it gives that query was empty

Comment: i think that you should try first your query directly on the database or check if there is something wrong with it. there might be something wrong with it. if there were no errors in your query then the error that you just had wouldn't have appeared.

Comment: in data base i am runing querry it shows result

Comment: i have tried in data base it works fine but not in php script same script if i run for only one table then i works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT ... ";
$result = mysql_query($query);//<=== add this line
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result  it gives this error when i run code

Comment: @AftabAli did you literally placed the 'select ...' ?

Comment: what literaly placed mean sorry i did not get that

Comment: @AftabAli all you ave to do is add `$result = mysql_query($query);` before `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: that what is given in @ramils edit i have also done like this

Comment: @Shiplu this is same as ramils edit i have done like this

Answer (score 0):

Can you please copy/paste the exact error message? Also try this simple `JOIN` query:

```
SELECT    
    PatientMaster.PatientFirstName,
    PatientMaster.PatientLastName,
    ProviderAppointmentListings.AppointmentTime 
FROM PatientMaster, ProviderAppointmentListings
WHERE 
    PatientMaster.PatientID = ProviderAppointmentListings.PatientID
```